# How do you perform one hot encoding with PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am having problems converting multiple columns from categorical to numerical values. I am using PySpark but I am sure the problem is not the version of spark I am using. When working with one column, there is no problem but I ran into problems when converting multiple columns. Here is the code, and there are no missing values:

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, OneHotEncoder, VectorAssembler
categorical_columns= ['age','job', 'marital','education', 'default', 'housing', 'loan', 'poutcome', 'y']

indexers = [
    StringIndexer(inputCol=c, outputCol="{0}_indexed".format(c))
    for c in categorical_columns
]

encoders = [OneHotEncoder(dropLast=False,inputCol=indexer.getOutputCol(),
            outputCol="{0}_encoded".format(indexer.getOutputCol())) 
    for indexer in indexers
]

# Vectorizing encoded values
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=[encoder.getOutputCol() for encoder in encoders],outputCol="features")

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexers + encoders+[assembler])
model=pipeline.fit(df2)
transformed = model.transform(df2)
transformed.show(5)
```

The output is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-452b475faf1a> in <module>
     20 
     21 pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexers + encoders+[assembler])
---> 22 model=pipeline.fit(df2)
     23 transformed = model.transform(df2)
     24 transformed.show(5)

E:\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
    130                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    131             else:
--> 132                 return self._fit(dataset)
    133         else:
    134             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

E:\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\pipeline.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    107                     dataset = stage.transform(dataset)
    108                 else:  # must be an Estimator
--> 109                     model = stage.fit(dataset)
    110                     transformers.append(model)
    111                     if i < indexOfLastEstimator:

E:\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
    130                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    131             else:
--> 132                 return self._fit(dataset)
    133         else:
    134             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

E:\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    293 
    294     def _fit(self, dataset):
--> 295         java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
    296         model = self._create_model(java_model)
    297         return self._copyValues(model)

E:\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py in _fit_java(self, dataset)
    290         """
    291         self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 292         return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
    293 
    294     def _fit(self, dataset):

E:\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

E:\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

E:\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1833.fit.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 79.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 79.0 (TID 72, localhost, executor driver): java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-11928db3-60f2-407b-b821-1338f779e3b5\0d\shuffle_30_0_0.data.6d622104-8179-4873-9b10-16afe2a61081 (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.initialize(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.WritablePartitionedPairCollection$$anon$1.writeNext(WritablePartitionedPairCollection.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.writePartitionedFile(ExternalSorter.scala:699)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:274)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$countByKey$1(PairRDDFunctions.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.countByKey(PairRDDFunctions.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$countByValue$1(RDD.scala:1214)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.countByValue(RDD.scala:1214)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer.fit(StringIndexer.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer.fit(StringIndexer.scala:109)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor87.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-11928db3-60f2-407b-b821-1338f779e3b5\0d\shuffle_30_0_0.data.6d622104-8179-4873-9b10-16afe2a61081 (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.initialize(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.WritablePartitionedPairCollection$$anon$1.writeNext(WritablePartitionedPairCollection.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.writePartitionedFile(ExternalSorter.scala:699)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

​

Comment: Are you sure about this `pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexers + encoders+[assembler])` ?

Comment: yeah coz I am simply concatenating them

Answer (score 5):

What was need was to convert for converting multiple columns from categorical to numerical values was the use of an indexer and an encoder for each of the columns then using a vector assembler. I also added a min-max scaler before using a vector assembler as shown:

```
stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="job", outputCol="job_index")
model = stringIndexer.fit(df2)
indexed = model.transform(df2)
encoder = OneHotEncoder(dropLast=False, inputCol="job_index", outputCol="job_vec")
encoded = encoder.transform(indexed)
df2 = encoded

stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="marital", outputCol="marital_index")
model = stringIndexer.fit(df2)
indexed = model.transform(df2)
encoder = OneHotEncoder(dropLast=False, inputCol="marital_index", outputCol="marital_vec")
encoded = encoder.transform(indexed)
df2 = encoded

stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="education", outputCol="education_index")
model = stringIndexer.fit(df2)
indexed = model.transform(df2)
encoder = OneHotEncoder(dropLast=False, inputCol="education_index", outputCol="education_vec")
encoded = encoder.transform(indexed)
df2 = encoded

stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="default", outputCol="default_index")
model = stringIndexer.fit(df2)
indexed = model.transform(df2)
encoder = OneHotEncoder(dropLast=False, inputCol="default_index", outputCol="default_vec")
encoded = encoder.transform(indexed)
df2 = encoded

stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="housing", outputCol="housing_index")
model = stringIndexer.fit(df2)
indexed = model.transform(df2)
encoder = OneHotEncoder(dropLast=False, inputCol="housing_index", outputCol="housing_vec")
encoded = encoder.transform(indexed)
df2 = encoded

stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="loan", outputCol="loan_index")
model = stringIndexer.fit(df2)
indexed = model.transform(df2)
encoder = OneHotEncoder(dropLast=False, inputCol="loan_index", outputCol="loan_vec")
encoded = encoder.transform(indexed)
df2 = encoded

stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="poutcome", outputCol="poutcome_index")
model = stringIndexer.fit(df2)
indexed = model.transform(df2)
encoder = OneHotEncoder(dropLast=False, inputCol="poutcome_index", outputCol="poutcome_vec")
encoded = encoder.transform(indexed)
df2 = encoded

stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="y", outputCol="y_index")
model = stringIndexer.fit(df2)
indexed = model.transform(df2)
encoder = OneHotEncoder(dropLast=False, inputCol="y_index", outputCol="y_vec")
encoded = encoder.transform(indexed)
df2 = encoded

df2.show(4)


cols = ['job', 'marital','education', 'default', 'housing', 'loan', 'poutcome', 'y']
for col in cols:
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(inputCol=col+"_vec", outputCol=col+"_vec_scaled")
    scalerModel = scaler.fit(df2)
    scaledData = scalerModel.transform(df2)
    df2 = scaledData
df2.show(4)
vecAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=[ '`job_vec_scaled','marital_vec_scaled','education_vec_scaled', 'default_vec_scaled', `'housing_vec`_scaled', 'loan_vec_scaled', 'poutcome_vec_scaled'], outputCol='features')`


df3 = vecAssembler.transform(df2)
df3.show(4)
```

Answer (score 4):

In Spark3

```
(trainingData, testData) = df.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])

si = StringIndexer(inputCols=["cat_col1", "cat_col2"], 
                   outputCols=["cat_col_si1", "cat_col_si2"])

ohe = OneHotEncoder(inputCols=["cat_col_si1", "cat_col_si2"], 
                    outputCols=["cat_col_ohe1", "cat_col_ohe2"])

assembler= VectorAssembler(inputCols=["num_col1", "num_col2"]+["cat_col_ohe1", "cat_col_ohe2"] , 
                           outputCol="features")

rf = RandomForestRegressor(featuresCol="features", labelCol="label")

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[si, ohe, assembler, rf])
pipeline = pipeline.fit(trainingData)
y_hat = pipeline.transform(testData)
```